# Различие IPython и Jupyter Notebook

Tags: jupyter-notebook, ipython

Чем IPython отличается от Jupyter Notebook?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**IPython** - это интерактивная текстовая (не веб) консоль ([REPL](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/REPL)) для Python. См. статью в Википедии: [IPython](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPython)

Выглядит примерно так:

[image: IPython]

**Jupyter Notebook** (ранее *IPython Notebook*) - веб-оболочка, в частности, для IPython. Изначально только с IPython и работал, но по мере развития был выделен в отдельный проект (собственно, [проект Jupyter](https://jupyter.org)), добавилась поддержка других языков программирования кроме Python: Julia и R (название Jupyter - это акроним от названий языков Julia, Python, R), и других (см. [Jupyter kernels](https://github.com/jupyter/jupyter/wiki/Jupyter-kernels)).

IPython и Jupyter тесно связаны (интегрируются между собой), но решают разные задачи.

Comment: Спасибо, теперь понятно

Answer (score -2):

Это одно и то же, только `Jupyter Notebook` - ребрендинг `IPython Notebook`а. Это маркетинг.

Comment: “ipython” и «ipython notebook» это не одно и то же.