# Различие Github-репозиториев для IPython и Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, ipython

В [предыдущем вопросе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/730606/270545) мы выяснили, что IPython и Jupyter Notebook это одно и то же. Скажите, пожалуйста, чем тогда отличаются следующие GitHub репозитории:

- https://github.com/ipython/ipython
- https://github.com/jupyter/notebook

Спасибо.

Comment: @stackflow, можно было бы, но на предыдущий вопрос всё равно больше никто не отвечает :(

Comment: 1. Не одно и то же. 2. Это разные проекты, поэтому разные репозитории. IPython сам по себе - это интерактивная консоль (не веб). Изначально Jupyter входил в IPython как "дополнение" (notebook), но потом был выделен в отдельный проект.